# BizTalk is trying to run "exec TDDS_GetColumnInfo @objectName=N'[dbo].[bam_xxx_PrimaryImport]'" against BizTalkDTADb database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-bam

I have deployed my BAM activities and they (tables/stored procs) exist in BAMPrimaryImport database. But I'm getting an error when the process runs:

> TDDS failed to execute event. Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.bam_xxx_PrimaryImport'.**

I ran the SQL Profiler and it shows it's trying to run the command below against **BizTalkDTADb** database!

```
exec TDDS_GetColumnInfo @objectName=N'[dbo].[bam_xxx_PrimaryImport]'**
```

Apparently bam_xxx_PrimaryImport does not exist in BizTalkDTADb .

So why it's trying to run that command against BizTalkDTADb database but not BAMPrimaryImport?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **Orphaned Tracking Profile** problem. You must have

1. Created a BAM Activity
2. Used TPE to create a tracking profile to capture data from your Biztalk application
3. Later you undeployed your BAM activity.

The solution is to find the file that defines your BAM activity and redeploy the activity using BM.

This usually happens while you are testing - by deploying and undeploying your BAM activities and changing your tracking profiles.

You can read more about this in '**Pro Business Activity Monitoring in Biztalk 2009 - Apress**'